# PYTHON basic ascii encryption function

Tags: python, utf-8, ascii, encode

When provided `text` as input string, and `rule` as input integer, challenge is to find ASCII value sum then convert back to string based on new numeric value.

My code appears on the right track, but given `ascii_encrypt("a",1)`, for example, my current output is `b'b'` when it should be `'b'`. I'm new to the encode function, which I'm guessing is tripping me up.

```
def ascii_encrypt(text, rule):
    text = sum([ord(c) for c in text])
    if not text:
        return ""
    else:
        encrypted_text = chr(text + rule)
        return encrypted_text.encode('utf-8')
```

Comment: Why are you encoding the result in UTF-8?

Comment: one test case had mixed letters, so i thought this would account for that

Comment: I dont understand what is the use of this line : `text = sum([ord(c) for c in text])` .   Do you want to use this function with strings larger than 1 character ?

Answer (score 2):

Simply remove, `.encode('utf-8')`. You don't need to encode it and it's causing your issue.  You can't include this part and achieve desired functionality.

```
def ascii_encrypt(text, rule):
    text = sum([ord(c) for c in text])
    if not text:
        return ""
    else:
        encrypted_text = chr(text + rule)
        return encrypted_text

print(ascii_encrypt("a",1))
```

Comment: What if I don't want to print but instead just return the value without encoding it?

Comment: Exactly, you don't need to print it or encode it.  Sending your strings as byte strings isn't a good idea.  Just leave the string not encoded.  If you could mark as solution, it'd help a lot.

Comment: here's what i get with the above code (minus print function): `UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\u0693' in position 11: ordinal not in range(128)`

Comment: @Mr.Jibz which line in the above code causes a UnicodeEncodeError? I can't see this happening, even if you are still using Python 2. (And in case you are: it's time to switch now!)